# News do not appear on a Morea Framework site after adding a news page

Tags: jekyll, morea-framework

Followed the [instructions for adding a news page](http://morea-framework.github.io/userguide.html#AddaNewspage) but posts still do [not](http://jce-il.github.io/se-class16b/news/) appear. Should I add a processing for posts in MoreaGenerator (e.g. by morea type)? thanks

p.s. the [rss feed](http://jce-il.github.io/se-class16b/feed.xml) is also broken

p.s.2 the 'url' property added to _config.yml causes link problems, e.g., in the calendar, by removing the course path in the site url.

---

Comment: Can you make you repository public ? It can help to debug.

Comment: Currently not, but I'll try to create a bare one with only this change, which is a good idea for debugging anyhow - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've created a public repo that illustrates the creation of a News page. It follows the instructions in the user guide, starting with the creation of a new Morea site. Here's the published site:

http://morea-framework.github.io/morea-news-page-example/

Here's the master branch containing the source for the site:

https://github.com/morea-framework/morea-news-page-example/tree/master

As far as I can tell, the current instructions are correct, so hopefully this example will help you track down what's going on in your site.

As for feed.xml, I am embarrassed to say that there was a bug.  In master/src/feed.xml, please change:

```
layout: default
```

to:

```
layout: null
```

You can see this fix in the example repo:

https://github.com/morea-framework/morea-news-page-example/blob/master/src/feed.xml

I've updated feed.xml in the core repo so future users won't encounter this problem.

Hope this helps.